# Convert HH:MM String to Time

Tags: datetime, time, stata

I have time stored in "HH:MM" format as strings (str13), but somehow cannot convert them to Stata internal format via the following (it generates missing values):

```
gen double time2 = clock(time, "HHMM")
```

What is the proper way of converting "HH:MM" strings to Stata Internal Format (SIF)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coding for the input format works differently than for the output format.

```
. set obs 1
number of observations (_N) was 0, now 1

. generate double t = clock("14:05","hm")

. format t %tcHH:MM

. list, clean noobs

        t  
    14:05
```